# Set Custom Design for frontend Module Page in Magento

Tags: templates, magento, module, frontend

I have a custom module in the Magento installation, I am displaying the details of the specific module in the frontend under the **URL**, `www.domain.com/modulename`. Now I have two designs one for cms pages and other for the checkout and catalog pages. I want this custom module page in the frontend to be displayed in the CMS page theme but my default template set in the backend is other one.

Is there any possible way available to set the custom design for this frontend module page like we do for the cms pages under the design tab.

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If your custom module can be accessed like this www.domain.com/modulename i guess that has own controller, maybe only if content is rendered from a static block, or cms page can change design from admin panel, otherwise i think that need to do this from code, or layout files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your own custom module (extension), then you can control the display of it's pages via module controllers. That includes the package/theme configuration. Here is a function code that can be used to control your module package and theme selection.

```
public function myAction()
{
  Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')
    ->setPackageName("myPackage")
    ->setTheme("myTheme");   
  $this->loadLayout();
  $this->renderLayout();
}
```

That's the only way at the moment of specifically setting custom package/theme for your action-controller-module.